# How to set an output from button (command = def()), as an input to Combobox values =

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox

I'm trying to set an input to `Combobox(values = output)` from other
function (which connected to `Button(command = some_function)`

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

def select():
    global sel
    a = ['101','102','103','104','105']
    b = ['201','202','203','204','205']
    sel = []
    #label.configure(text = " Fleet" + fleet.get())
    choosed = fleet.curselection()
    for i in choosed:
        selection = fleet.get(i)
        print ("selected " + " " + selection)
        if selection == 'B':
            sel = b
        else: sel = a
    #print (sel)
    return sel

root =Tk()
fleet = Listbox(root, width = 10, height = 2)
fleet.insert(1, 'B')
fleet.insert(2, 'A')
fleet.grid(column = 1, row = 0)

label = ttk.Label(root, text = "Please choose the fleet")
label.grid (column = 0, row = 0)

button1 = ttk.Button(root, text = 'Select', command = select)
button1.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

a = ['101','102','103','104','105']
b = ['201','202','203','204','205']

combo_tool_num = ttk.Combobox(root, width = 10, values = sel)
```

I would like to set an `select()` output `sel`, as an input for: `combo_tool_num values = sel`.
Thank you!

Comment: You can't do what you want. **1.** A function used as `command=select` can't return anything. **2.** At the time you want to assign `values=sel`, `sel` is undefined. **Solution**: Init with empyt values: `values=[]`. In `def select()` do `combo_tool_num['values'] = a`. Read [Combobox](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#combobox)

Comment: It works!!! Great answer thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Feel free to post a community wiki answer, checkbox lower right, to show your solution.

Answer (score 0):

To set initial value in combobox use 'set()'
Use syntax as,
combo_tool_num = ttk.Combobox(root, width = 10, values = sel)
combo_tool_num.set('Select')